# Eloquent Model: Define on-to-one relationship using flag on child table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables `vendors` and `partners`

`vendors` table only stores the name of some company and `partners` table store users who work for some company. So the structure is somethign like this:

**vendors**

```
|  id  |   name        |
+------+---------------+
|   1  |   Vendor-1    |
|   2  |   Vendor-2    |
|   3  |   Vendor-3    |
```

**Partners**

```
| id | user_name  | password  |vendor_id |  is_owner  |  is_admin  | is_technitian |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+---------------+
| 1  | abc        | ^&ASKJHA  |    1     |    1       |      1     |      0        | 
| 2  | def        | ^&ASKJHA  |    2     |    1       |      1     |      0        |
| 3  | ghi        | ^&ASKJHA  |    1     |    0       |      1     |      0        |
| 4  | jkl        | ^&ASKJHA  |    3     |    1       |      1     |      0        |
| 5  | mno        | ^&ASKJHA  |    1     |    0       |      0     |      1        |
| 6  | pqr        | ^&ASKJHA  |    2     |    0       |      1     |      0        |
| 7  | stu        | ^&ASKJHA  |    1     |    0       |      0     |      1        |
| 8  | vwx        | ^&ASKJHA  |    2     |    0       |      0     |      1        |
| 9  | yz         | ^&ASKJHA  |    3     |    0       |      0     |      1        |
```

So as you can see above that One partner is the owner of any vendor and rest of them work as employees for the vendor.

I am working with Eloquent ORM and i have already defined Models for both Partner and vendor. I want to add an `owner` method in the Vendor Model so i can directly access the owner for any vendor Object. What i want to know is how do i relate this in my model defination. Is it do-able or do i need to make some changes in my database structure ?

```
class Vendor extends Model{

  /**
   * Get all the users for this vendor
   */
  public function users(){
     $this->hasMany(Partner::class);
  }

  public function owner(){
    // how do i relate one owner from partner model who has is_owner == 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `where()`

```
public function owner(){
    $this->hasOne(Partner::class)->where('is_owner', true);
}
```

You may have to specify the foreign key in the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a new relationship, and leading to duplicate code and breaking the DRY principle, make use of **Local Scopes** which comes out of the box in Eloquent ORM.

> Local scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you may easily re-use throughout your application. For example, you may need to frequently retrieve all users that are considered "popular". To define a scope, simply prefix an Eloquent model method with scope.
>
> Scopes should always return a query builder instance:

for instance:- define a function ScopeOwner() in your Vendor model such as:

```
public function scopeOwner($query)
{
    return $query->where('is_owner', 1);
}
```

and then use it in your controller or implement it as follows:

```
$vendor->users()->owner()->get();
```

> Once the scope has been defined, you may call the scope methods when querying the model. However, you do not need to include the scope prefix when calling the method. You can even chain calls to various scopes.

What's next, you could even use dynamic scopes to get even better code re-usage.

> Sometimes you may wish to define a scope that accepts parameters. To get started, just add your additional parameters to your scope. Scope parameters should be defined after the $query parameter:

```
public function scopeOfType($query, $type)
{
    return $query->where('is_owner', $type);
}
```

and consume it as follows:

```
$vendor->users()->ofType(0)->get();
```

for more information, check back to official docs: [Eloquent ORM Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes)